# simple game, while loop and checking strings

Tags: c++, iterator, do-while

I am a beginner at c++ and I want to create simple game. You have vector of strings, then you check if line input matched the right answer.

I want to generate random number 1 ,2 or 3. Then check if line matches correct answer and count the points.

I am probably missing something basic, yet I dont know what.

Problems:

- Input line get correctly read on only first iterations
- somehow points (tocke) jumps to 45763 after finishing.
- At beginning time (cas) is sometimes 2.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <string>



int main() {
    int runde;
    int tocke;
    int cas;
    std::cout <<  "\n" << "Pravila igre:" << "\n" << "Za pravilen odgovor dobis 1 tocko, za napacnega zgubis 2!"<<
      "\n" << "Stevilo zivljenj si izberes sama!"<< "\n" << "\n" ;
    std::cout << "Izberi stevilo zivljenj!:" << "\n";
    std::cin >> runde ;
    std::vector<std::string> latin = {"carum carvi", "artemisia absiinthium","coriandrum sativum"};
    std::vector<std::string> slovene = {"navadna kumina", "pravi pelin", "koriander"};
    tocke << 0;
    cas << 0;

    do {
        int ind;
        cas << cas + 1;
        std::cout << "Round  " << cas  <<"! Ladies and gentlemans, buckle your seatbelts!"<<"\n" << "\n" ;
        ind = std::rand() % 3;
        std::cout << "ime rastline: " << slovene[ind] << "\n";
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::string line;
        getline(std::cin, line);
        std::cout << "\n";
        if (latin[ind] == line){
            std::cout << "Pravlino! Tocka zate!" << "\n"; 
            tocke << tocke + 1;
            std::cout << "Tocke == " << tocke << "\n" << "Zivjenja == " << runde << "\n" << "Prezivete runde == " << cas << "\n"<< "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Napaka! :D" << "\n";
            std::cout << "Pravilen odgovor == " << latin[ind] << "\n";
            -- runde ;
            tocke << tocke - 2;
            std::cout << "Tocke == " << tocke << "\n" << "Zivjenja == " << runde << "\n"  << "Prezivete runde == " << cas << "\n"<< "\n";
        }        
    }while(runde >= 0 );  
    std::cout << "\n"<<"Stevilo tock == " << tocke <<"\n" << "St. prezivetih rund == " << cas - 1
    << "\n" ;

}
```

Comment: `tocke << tocke + 1;`is not how you add one to a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a misconception regarding operators. `<<` is NOT assignment, use `=` instead. So `tocke << 0;` doesn't assign `0` to `tocke`, it does bitshifting (on an uninitialized variable), then discards the result. `tocke` stays uninitialized and this causes problems later.

Instead of this:

```
tocke << 0;
cas << 0;
```

Do this:

```
tocke = 0;
cas = 0;
```

Also instead of `cas << cas + 1;` do `cas++` and instead of `tocke << tocke - 2;` do `tocke -= 2;`. To learn how the assignment operators work, you can read about them [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment). Last but not least, try to see if your compiler gives you any warnings, it should complain about using uninitialized values.